# Updating Multiple Values in the Same Column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data table called Movie_Stars. I want to update multiple values, but they are all in the same column. Here's what I have:

```
update movie_stars
set movie_category = 'Family'
where movie_category = 'Drama'
and set movie_category = 'Children'
where movie_category = 'Cartoon'
and set movie_category = 'Teen'
where movie_category = 'Action';
```

But this generates the error "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification". So what is the right column specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
update movie_stars
set movie_category = case when movie_category = 'Drama'
                          then 'Family'
                          when movie_category = 'Cartoon'
                          then 'Children'
                          when movie_category = 'Action'
                          then 'Teen'
                     end
where movie_category in ('Drama', 'Cartoon', 'Action')
```

Comment: sorry, but when I run you code, it says "invalid relational operator".

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I had a typo in there, please try again.  Great first name, by the way!